# Value stored in 'parameter name' is never read in commented Macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I'm using different Macros in order to log different sections of my app. This way I can "turn off" some of the logging using comments.

Example:

```
String *logValue = @"This is some log text")
```

and then:

```
NetworkLog(@"%@", logValue);
SessionLog(@"%@", logValue);
```

I can turn off all session logs in my app by commenting that specific Macro code and leaving the network logs active.
When I turn off that specific Macro I get an analyzer warning:

> Value stored in 'logValue' is never read

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark the variable as "unused", that should prevent the warning.

```
__unused NSString *logValue = @"This is some log text";
```

or

```
__attribute__((unused)) NSString *logValue = @"This is some log text";
```

Comment: marking the variable as unused will prevent me from using them?

Comment: No, it just prevents the warning about it not being used. There's no inverse warning about using an `__unused`.

Comment: what will be the Swift equivalent?